# How can I update my post_count for each user when they add a new post?

Tags: python, django, count

I made a function and called it in the main view when the user add a post. But the post_count is not updating when i'm adding new posts and I'm getting this error:

```
`type object 'Post' has no attribute 'post_count'
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is my view.py:

```
def create_post(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pform = PostForm(data=request.POST, prefix='PostForm')
        if pform.is_valid():

            new_post = pform.save(commit=False)
            new_post.user = request.user
            post_count(request, new_post.user)
            new_post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/forum/all')
    else:
        pform = PostForm()

    return render_to_response('forum/createpost.html',
                              {'pform': pform},
                              context)
```

This is my function to count update the number of posts per user.

```
def post_count(request, user, **kwargs):
        if user:
            Post.post_count += 1
            Post.save()
```

Comment: Did you do the migration after editing the model?

Comment: You are sure you want to work with a class variable?

Comment: @JesseBakker Hi, yes the migration went fine. To count logins per user worked fine and I wanted to try the same for posts.

Comment: @flaschbier How do you suggest I do it?

Comment: I would use a relationship between users and posts for this. But if you want to use this model, I would do this on a Post object, not on the class ;)

Comment: I would `self.title = ...` in `Post.__init__` and the so with the others to make it instance variables. But beware, I am not into `django` so this can be completely wrong path...

Answer (score 0):

```
def post_count(request, user, **kwargs):
    if user:
        user.post_count += 1
        user.save()
```

Pass your post object to the function then change the post_count on the object, instead of the class.

post_count on a post does not make much sense. Don't you mean to do it on a user?

Comment: Yes, I have to update the count for every user when the user add a post. so should I move post_count to my User model?

Comment: @Selena Then you should change your User model. As you are using the auth models, you should first extend the user with a one-to-one relationship to be able to add the field.

Comment: Yes okay. I'll try do that and see if it works. Thank you for your time.